# CMS block not saving code

Tags: cache, ce-1.9.0.1, static-block

I am trying to edit a simple static block in Magento **1.9.0.1**. 
The static block is the main page of the Ma-Cance theme. 
When I try to add a `<p class="img5"></p>` to the static block, and add some content, then save it... it throws away the code I just added.

I have no clue why this is happening...

The webstore is on a local Xampp server. 
I have cleared all Magento's general caches and all other cache options are turned off...

Does anyone know what is happening?

**SIDE NOTE: I know how to code in the Wysiwyg editor by using the Show/Hide button**

**EDIT 1**: 
Turning off the Wysiwyg editor seems to give me back my code, but why doesn't it save the code when it is turned on by default?

Comment: Make sure that you are adding html codes in html part of CMS. You most probably adding html content inside content section. In order to switch to html part, you can use `Show| Hide Editor` button

Comment: I know how the Wysiwyg editor works... the problem is it doesn't save anything.

Comment: Turning off the Wysiwyg editor seems to give me back my code, but why doesn't it save the code when it is turned on by default?

Comment: TinyMce will do some code cleanup with will probably remove unused elements, I know it validates the html and has a set to things to look for.

Comment: @GrayleBV : Sometime I noted that html elements without any content inside it will be erased | moved my editor before it saving the contents. So try add some conent inside that `<p />` and then try again

Comment: If you only add a <div> without content you will never see it, just like you dont see the divs inside the pages. Its because the WYSIWYG editor is "rendering" the HTML. I dont think this is an issue.

Comment: Quote: "When I try to add a <p class="img5"></p> to the static block, **and add some content**, then save it... it throws away the code I just added". - So even with content added it doesn't save.

Comment: Did you checked the DB? Is the block present there with the info you added?

Comment: Yes it is, it worked before. After an edit it doesn't save, but the old parts remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding HTML, first click on :

> Show/Hide Editor

to disable the tools of editor and then add you tags

This [LINK](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/268262/) have a discussion and may help you out.

Comment: Clicking on the Show/Hide Editor button a couple of times to disable the tools does not work. I know how the editor works... It is just not saving any added code changes.

Comment: Try this link, I guess this can help you out:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/268262/

Comment: thanks, this seems to be the solution. Now to figgure out how to edit it ;)

Comment: Please verify and confirm if it worked

Comment: it seems to work when you configure the TinyMCE. However I haven't figured out how to configure the TinyMCE correctly to what we need. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

[image: You need to click on Show/Hide Editor Button]

[image: Then you need to add your code here, when the looks like below:]

You need to click on "Show/Hide Editor" Button if your window looks like just below
Then you need to add your code here, when the looks like below:

Comment: 1. Your second image doesn't work; 2. Read the above answer / all other comments **AND** the side note in the question description. Thank you!